# Animating changes to an observable value

Tags: javascript, animation, mvvm, knockout.js

I'd like to animate a change to an individual `ko.observable` in the most MVVM/Knockoutesque way.  I can handle the animation and view updates on my own:

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.value = ko.observable("start value");
    $("button").on("click", function () {
        $("#text").animate(animateOutProperties,
        {
            complete: function () {
                self.value($("#value").val());
                $("#text").animate(animateInProperties);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

[The above works exactly as I want it to](http://jsfiddle.net/c8ssN/1/)

However, the above does not take full advantage of two way data binding since I'm actually listening to an event and changes on the value itself.  There's almost no point in using `data-bind: text` since I can just use jQuery to update the text at this point.

Using something like `self.value.subscribe` to listen to changes in the value would make more sense to me and I could use other bindings to update the value -- *however*, as far as I can tell there is no way to get both the old and new values at the same time.

I want to use something like `beforeRemove` and `afterAdd`, but those only work for adding and removing `observableArray` elements.

Is there a way to handle the above animation that fits better with the MVVM/two way data binding philosophy?

Comment: @nemesv but how do you get the new value at that point?

Comment: I've realized that you want to get both the old and new value in the same time, so I've removed my comment. However you can store internally the old value and when you get the new value then you do the animate using the old value from your temp store.

Comment: take a look at this https://github.com/knockout/knockout/pull/320 for a way to get the old value and new value together in a callback.

Comment: @nemesv thinking about it now, that would not necessarily help since I would essentially have to defer writing the new value until the animation completes.  This would require some middleware to intercept the addition (probably how `beforeRemove`/`afterAdd` work).